# A list of verbs that take only dative objects

Tags: verb, grammatical-case

It appears that there must be dozens of verbs in German that take dative objects but never take accusative objects.  "Helfen" and "folgen" are frequently seen examples. I just came across "nachgehen". And suddenly it occurred to me to wonder if a moderately comprehensive list exists.  Does it?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: **Please do not post LMGTFY-links** or the like. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found in my word list the following 90+ verbs that take dative objects:

> (etw. (D)) lauschen |lauschte, gelauscht| = listen (to sth.)
>
> (jdm) unterliegen |unterlag, unterlegen| = lose (to sb)
>
> (jdm.) winken |winkte, gewinkt| = beckon (sb.); wave (to sb.)
>
> etw. (D) abhelfen |half ab, abgeholfen| = redress sth.
>
> etw. (D) abschwören |schwor ab, abgeschworen| = renounce sth.
>
> etw. (D) angehören |gehörte an, angehört| = belong to sth.
>
> etw. (D) anhängen |hing an, angehangen| = adhere to sth.
>
> etw. (D) ausweichen |wich aus, ausgewichen| = avoid sth.; divert sth.
>   [aviat.]
>
> etw. (D) begegnen |begegnete, begegnet| = face sth.; respond to sth.
>
> etw. (D) beikommen |kam bei, beigekommen| = cope with sth.
>
> etw. (D) beitreten |trat bei, beigetreten| = join sth.
>
> etw. (D) beiwohnen |wohnte bei, beigewohnt| = attend sth.
>
> etw. (D) entgegenstehen |stand entgegen, entgegengestanden| = be an
>   obstacle to sth.
>
> etw. (D) entgegentreten |trat entgegen, entgegengetreten| = counter
>   sth.
>
> etw. (D) entgegenwirken |wirkte entgegen, entgegengewirkt| =
>   counteract sth.
>
> etw. (D) entrinnen |entrann, entronnen| = escape (from) sth.
>
> etw. (D) entsagen |entsagte, entsagt| = renounce sth.
>
> etw. (D) entsprechen |entsprach, entsprochen| = correspond to sth.
>
> etw. (D) entstammen |entstammte, entstammt| = be descended from sth.
>
> etw. (D) erliegen |erlag, erlegen| = succumb to sth.
>
> etw. (D) genügen |genügte, genügt| = satisfy sth.
>
> etw. (D) gleichen |glich, geglichen| = equal sth.; be like sth.
>
> etw. (D) gleichkommen | kam gleich, gleichgekommen| = be tantamount to
>   sth.
>
> etw. (D) hinterherhinken |hinkte hinterher, hinterhergehinkt| = lag
>   behind sth.
>
> etw. (D) nachgehen |ging nach, nachgegangen| = pursue sth.
>
> etw. (D) nachhelfen |half nach, nachgeholfen| = assist sth.
>
> etw. (D) nachkommen |kam nach, nachgekommen| = fulfill sth.; meet sth.
>
> etw. (D) schaden |schadete, geschadet| = damage sth.
>
> etw. (D) stattgeben |gab statt, stattgegeben| = allow sth. [law]; grant sth. [law]
>
> etw. (D) unterliegen |unterlag, unterlegen| = be subject to sth.
>
> etw. (D) vorauseilen |eilte voraus, vorausgeeilt| = be ahead of sth.
>
> etw. (D) vorausgehen |ging voraus, vorausgegangen| = precede sth.
>
> etw. (D) vorbeugen |beugte vor, vorgebeugt| = prevent sth.
>
> etw. (D) vorsitzen |saß vor, vorgesessen| = preside over sth.
>
> etw. (D) wehren |wehrte, gewehrt| = fight sth.
>
> etw. (D) widersprechen |widersprach, widersprochen| = contradict sth.;
>   object to sth.
>
> etw. (D) widerstehen |widerstand, widerstanden| = resist sth.
>
> etw. (D) zürnen |zürnte, gezürnt| = rage against sth.
>
> etw. (D) zustimmen |stimmte zu, zugestimmt| = approve of sth.; agree
>   with sth.
>
> etw. (D) zuwiderhandeln |handelte zuwider, zuwidergehandelt| = act
>   contrary to sth.
>
> etw. (D) zuwiderlaufen |lief zuwider, zuwidergelaufen| = adversely
>   affect sth.; run contrary to sth.
>
> jdm blühen |blühte, geblüht| = be in store for sb.
>
> jdm dämmern |dämmerte, gedämmert| = (gradually) dawn on sb
>
> jdm entgegenfahren |fuhr entgegen, entgegengefahren| = go to meet sb
>
> jdm zupasskommen |kam zupass, zupassgekommen| = come to sb. at the
>   right time
>
> jdm. abwinken |winkte ab, abgewinkt| = stop sb. with a wave of one's
>   hand
>
> jdm. auffallen |fiel auf, aufgefallen| = occur to sb.
>
> jdm. aufsitzen |saß auf, aufgesessen| = be fooled by sb.
>
> jdm. behagen |behagte, behagt| = please sb.
>
> jdm. beispringen |sprang bei, beigesprungen| = come to sb's assistance
>
> jdm. beistehen |stand bei, beigestanden| = assist sb.; support sb.
>
> jdm. einfallen |fiel ein, eingefallen| = occur to sb. [come to mind]
>
> jdm. entgegengehen |ging entgegen, entgegengegangen| = go to meet sb.
>
> jdm. entgegenschlagen |schlug entgegen, entgegengeschlagen| = confront
>   sb.; meet sb.
>
> jdm. fernliegen |lag fern, ferngelegen| = be far from sb.'s
>   thoughts/mind
>
> jdm. gebühren |gebührte, gebührt| = be due to sb.
>
> jdm. gefallen |gefiel, gefallen| = please sb.
>
> jdm. gegenübersitzen |saß gegenüber, gegenübergesessen| = sit facing
>   sb.
>
> jdm. hineinreden |redete hinein, hineingeredet| = meddle in sb.'s
>   affairs
>
> jdm. leichtfallen |fiel leicht, leichtgefallen| = be easy for sb.
>
> jdm. liegen |lag, gelegen| = suit sb.
>
> jdm. nachfolgen |folgte nach, nachgefolgt| = succeed sb.
>
> jdm. nachhängen |hing nach, nachgehangen| = stick to sb.
>
> jdm. nahegehen |ging nahe, nahegegangen| = affect sb. deeply;
>
> jdm. nahestehen |stand nahe, nahegestanden| = be close to sb.
>
> jdm. passen |passte, gepasst| = suit sb.
>
> jdm. schmeicheln |schmeichelte, geschmeichelt| = flatter sb.
>
> jdm. vorkommen |kam vor, vorgekommen| = seem to sb.
>
> jdm. vorliegen |lag vor, vorgelegen| = be received by sb.
>
> jdm. wehtun |tat weh, wehgetan| = hurt sb.
>
> jdm. zugehen |ging zu, zugegangen| = reach sb. [letter]
>
> jdm. zuprosten |prostete zu, zugeprostet| = raise one's glass to sb.
>
> jdm. zurufen |rief zu, zugerufen| = shout to sb.; call out to sb.
>
> jdm. zusehen |sah zu, zugesehen| = watch sb.
>
> jdm. zusetzen |setzte zu, zugesetzt| = press sb.; afflict sb.
>
> jdm. zustehen |stand zu, zugestanden| = be entitled to sth. [money,
>   leave, respect]
>
> jdm. zustoßen |stieß zu, zugestoßen| = happen to sb.
>
> jdm./etw. anhaften |haftete an, angehaftet| = cling to sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. entgehen |entging, entgangen| = escape sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. entkommen |entkam, entkommen| = escape sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. gegenüberstehen |stand gegenüber, gegenübergestanden| = face
>   sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. gehorchen |gehorchte, gehorcht| = obey sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. gelten |galt, gegolten| = be directed at sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. nachsetzen |setzte nach, nachgesetzt| = pursue sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. nachstellen |stellte nach, nachgestellt| = go after sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. nützen |nützte, genützt| = benefit sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. nutzen |nutzte, genutzt| = benefit sb./sth. [hauptsächlich
>   (Norddt.)]
>
> jdm./etw. weichen |wich, gewichen| = make way for sb./sth.
>
> jdm./etw. zukommen |kam zu, zugekommen| = be due to sb./sth.
>   [zustehen, gebühren]
>
> jdm./etw. zuvorkommen |kam zuvor, zuvorgekommen| = preempt sb./sth.
>
> jdm/etw ähneln |ähnelte, geähnelt| = resemble sb./sth.
>
> jdm/etw gegenüberliegen |lag gegenüber, gegenübergelegen| = face / be
>   opposite sb/sth
>
> jdm/etw hinterherfahren |fuhr hinterher, hinterhergefahren| = follow /
>   drive behind sb/sth
>
> jdm/etw hinterherhecheln |hechelte hinterher, hinterhergehechelt| =
>   try to catch up with sb/sth

Comment: I recall "beitreten".

Comment: @Michael Hardy Your comment made me wonder why I didn't locate "beitreten" in my word list. So, I changed my search parameters and came up with 7 more verbs, which I added to the list above.

Comment: Note that "anhängen" can also be used with a dative object and an accusative object ("*jemandem eine Sache anhängen*"), or with an accusative object plus an optional prepositional phrase ("*den Waggon (an einen Zug) anhängen*").

Comment: "nutzen" can also be used with an accusative object.

Comment: raten, folgen, helfen, danken, gefallen, sumuten, vertrauen, trauen, verziehen, begegnen, huldigen, ähneln, bedürfen, dienen

Comment: "glauben", unlike English "believe" can take both a dative object and an accusative object. In English one can say "She believes him" or "She believes every word", and either way it's a direct object. One wouldn't include both objects in the same sentence.

Comment: @Michael Hardy "bedürfen" requires Genitiv.

Comment: Typo: I meant "zumuten".

Comment: @MichaelHardy "zumuten" takes a dative object and an accusative object ("*jemandem etwas zumuten*").

Comment: I came across this one: "Er hat der Versamlung ferngeblieben."

Comment: A related thing is verbs that when used in one sense take dative objects and in another sense accusative. Thus: "Er befahl mir etwas zu tun." and "Er befahl mich zu sich."

Comment: @MichaelHardy That sounds wrong. Should it not be "er *ist* der Versammlung ferngeblieben"?

Comment: @Peter Correct, must be *ist*.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica : I think what I read was actually this: "Er war der Versammlung ferngeblieben."

Comment: @RHa : See above.