# Which case is the right one?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative, relative-pronoun

Can someone explain to me why here the relative pronoun belongs to a different case? Because I don't see the difference between the two sentences ... (that's from an exercise in my German book)

> Die Freunde, **denen** wir im Kino begegneten, waren sehr freundlich. (Plural / dative, right?)
>
> "The friends that we met in the cinema were really nice."

> Der Junge, **den** wir in den Ferien kennengelernt haben, spricht sehr gut Deutsch. (Masculine / accusative, right?)
>
> "The boy that we met on holidays speaks good German."

Comment: "begegneten haben" is wrong in multiple ways, please check your book again. Also, it's "freu**n**dlich".

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the missing "n". Also my book is an old one (still talks in Deutschmarks) but begegneten is written black on white.. Do you maybe have an answer to my question though ? :)

Comment: Is it "begegneten haben", though?

Comment: As for the case, the verbs *begegnen* and *kennenlernen* require different cases (A good dictionary will tell which). Apart from that, the number is different, because it's several friends in the first sentence and one boy in the second.

Comment: Jesus, so many words everywhere. Sorry. It is definitely not haben. I correct it. Then I guess it makes all the difference and explains why it is a dative ?

Comment: No, I just like to see questions in decent shape before they are answered, because the pessimist in me thinks that the chance of a correction goes down once answers have been posted. I am a grumpy old man, sometimes.

Comment: @Lisalcz While I've heard the term *Deutschmark* is used outside of Germany, you might want to notice that it does *not* exist in German. It's either *Mark*, *D-Mark* or *Deutsche Mark*. If *Mark* on its own isn't clear enough, the most common is *D-Mark*. However, *Deutschmark* is never used in German.

Comment: @CarstenS No, please, there was nothing sarcastic in my answers, I am happy that someone like you doesnt answer to the pointed mistake only ! I think it is important :) Specially because i am looking for something close to perfect german language ! And i do hope this forum (which i am completely new to) has the same intention. That doesnt make you a grumpy person ! (as for the " old man" part , I cant tell :)

Comment: @amadeusamadeus, yes, I was just afraid that writting it in german in the middle of an english sentence might confuse people with the english word "mark". Thanks for the preciseness though !

Comment: @Lisalcz Sure, for English speakers it might be more clear this way, however many German speakers get confused by this and would deem it plain wrong because it has never been an official name of the currency, rather beeing colloquial English.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus and you are completely right for doing it, Next time i use this word i will definitely make it clear. Thank you !

Comment: Probably helpful: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33817/35111

Comment: It's all good. By the way, I said that "begegneten haben" is wrong in multiple ways, one of them is indeed somewhat related to your question, using the perfect tense it would have been "begegnet sind". I have added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The words *begegnen* and *kennenlernen* are different verbs. While both have similar meanings, they go with different cases. It is

> jemande**m** begegnen (Dativ)

but

> jemande**n** kennenlernen (Akkusativ).

I am afraid that you will have to learn the case together with each verb.

Note that there is another grammatical category for verbs that is related, but not strictly. Verbs that take an accusative object tend to form the perfect tense with "haben":

> Ich habe ihn kennengelernt.

On the other hand, the verb *begegnen* goes with *sein*:

> Ich bin ihm begegnet.

Comment: Perfekt ! Thank you so much